# <head> section not being read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, head

I'm a beginner to coding and have what seems to be a beginner question.  I'm working in Ruby on Rails.

It appears that (all of a sudden) my application is ignoring my  section across all of my pages.  The implications are that the title is not appearing on the browser tabs and the css is not rendering in the mobile production environment (although it is working on desktop dev/prod and mobile prod). the code is below.  Can someone help me?  Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Home | XXXX</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be inside  tag. Please check your code. Hope this will help you.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home | XXXX</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
    </head>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!.  However, my apologies - I already had the <html> tag there (and at the bottom).  If that's the only edit, it doesn't appear to be working.  Any other ideas?